# Phaser 3 doesn't apply font family even when set

Tags: fonts, phaser-framework, phaserjs

The font itself is applied, but it's not applied initially on load

Is there an event or method in Phaser 3 to check if a font has been loaded? How can I set and apply a font family in Phaser 3?

I'm curious if it's possible to handle it within Phaser 3 without using external libraries.

Comment: I just wanted to know did my answer solve your problem. if so please consider accepting it with the green checkmark under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 0):

If you ***don't*** want to use a library, like a Web Font Loader from google, like shown in [this official phaser example](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/game%20objects/text/google%20webfont.js&v=3.60.0), you could simply postpone the creation of the `Phaser.Game` Object until the styles are loaded, the `load` event of the window should do, if this is not too late for you.

**Something like:**

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => new Phaser.Game(config));
```

> *Or in that event call a function, that inturn calls a function on the current running Phaser Scene, that tells the game the font is ready.*

> *Or **alternatively** you could use phaser's bitmap fonts, you just would have to load them on `preload` ([link to a official example](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/loader/bitmap%20text/load%20bitmap%20text.js))*